# Zend Framework menu.xml in module throws exception

Tags: zend-framework, zend-navigation

Usually I have a navigation file menu.xml in configs folder for Zend_Navigation.

Now when I put it in modules/module-name/configs/ I get the error:

**Section 'production' cannot be found in /blah/blah/blah/menu.xml**.

I understand [production] is the section for config ini files, do I need it in xml as well? Am I missing something really obvious? How could I have navigation xml files in the module directory (to keep modules independent)?

Answer (score 0):

OK this is what I had to do to make it work. Everything based just on trial/error, I don't know underlying mechanisms why it had to be this way and not the "normal" way (like it works without modules).

The file must have a *production* node, and it must be used for config for Zend_Navigation in module's Bootstrap.php:

```
$config = new Zend_Config_Xml( APPLICATION_PATH . '/modules/default/configs/navigation.xml', 'production' );
$container = new Zend_Navigation( $config );
```

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configdata>
    <production>        
            <page1>
                <label>My page 1</label>
                <controller>page</controller>
                <action>index</action>
            </page1>
<!-- more pages here -->
    </production>
</configdata>
```

I have no idea why it has to be that way (or is it possible to have it any other way) so I'd appreciate if you tell it in comments, if you know it ;)

Comment: Remove the 'production' from the Zend_Config_Xml call

Comment: I can't, because production is the node that needs to be called for menu. If I rename that node, ZF immediately complains about "production" not being found (as per original question). Note that this "lack of production section" error comes before Zend_Config_Xml is even called, probably ZF beforehand parses every file it finds in Configs dir to check if they have 'production' section.

Comment: That is strange. I have my navigation section defined as "nav" and it works fine with this call: $config = new Zend_Config_Xml(APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/navigation.xml','nav');

As long as the second parameter in the Zend_Config_Xml function is the name of the node, you should be fine. If you pass it 'production' then it will look for production, if you pass it 'foobar' it will look for foobar.

Comment: It works for me as well, as long as it resides within /configs. Aforementioned nonsense happens only if I make it module-specific, i.e. /modules/admin/configs/navigation.xml.